# Who is Sasha in the movie Iron Man: Rise of Technovore?

Tags: marvel, character-motivation

In the animated movie *Iron Man: Rise of Technovore*, Ezekiel Stane was working with Sasha. Who is Sasha? What was her role in the development of Technovore, and her bond with Ezekiel? Is she present in any other Marvel animated series?

Comment: https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Sasha_Hammer_(Earth-101001)